# If $4x^{10}-x^9-3x^8+5x^7+kx^6+2x^5-x^3+kx^2+5x-5 $ when divided by $(x+1)$ gives a remainder of -14, then the value of k equals?

Tags: polynomials

If $4x^{10}-x^9-3x^8+5x^7+kx^6+2x^5-x^3+kx^2+5x-5 $ when divided by $(x+1)$ gives a remainder of -14, then the value of k equals?

I got this and similar type of question in a book and I don't really know how to exactly solve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @egreg why did you censor your comment ? was it wrong ?

Comment: @Evariste what do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=4x^{10}-x^9-3x^8+5x^7+kx^6+2x^5-x^3+kx^2+5x-5 $. Then $f(-1)=-14$ since the remainder when we divide by $x+1$ is $-14$.

So, $4+1-3-5+k-2+1+k-5-5=-14$
Thus, $2k=4$and $k=2$

Comment: So for this kind of question we just substitute -1 randomly?

Comment: You might want to check the factor theorem.

Comment: Can you provide any link @daruma

Comment: It's in almost any common textbook on high school algebra. Google "Factor theorem" . You will get a lot of results. But if you really insist on a reference, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem